# What is the proper protocol prior to the meeting where an inventor will be negotiating his patent pending invention to a corporation?

Tags: licensing

An inventor's patent is pending approval.

He is now soliciting corporations to either buy or license his patent pending invention. What must he and the corporation sign before the meeting where he will present the invention and negotiate a deal?

Is it common to sign a confidentiality contract where the corporation agrees to not disclose or use his invention even in the event of a no-deal?

Comment: This is off topic here but on topic at Law SE.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off topic here. I will say that confidentiality agreements are common but less important if you already have filed your application.